# Apache Spark SQL Jar - No Row interface found

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

This is probably some confusion with Apache Spark jars, however, I am unable to solve this. The spark sql jat that is found under 'jars' directory contains the spark sql jar, however the jar does not contain the Row interface calss:

[image: image attached]

Are any other jars need to be included to get the Row interface, Spark javadoc states that it is under the package org.apache.spark.sql

Will really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in spark-catalyst subproject, not main spark-sql.

Search for `org.apache.spark:spark-catalyst` dependency

Comment: Thanks, could solve it, the spark-catalyst jar is in the jar directory